# Encoding lost when reading XML in R

Tags: r, xml, encoding, utf-8, sdmx

I am retrieving online XML data using the `XML` R packages. My issue is that the UTF-8 encoding is lost during the call to `xmlToList` : for instance, 'é' are replaced by 'Ã©'. This happens during the XML parsing.

Here is a code snippet, with an example of encoding lost and another where encoding is kept (depending of the data source) :

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url = "http://www.bdm.insee.fr/series/sdmx/data/DEFAILLANCES-ENT-FR-ACT/M.AZ+BE.BRUT+CVS-CJO?lastNObservations=2"
res <- getURL(url)
xmlToList(res)
# encoding lost

url2 = "http://www.bdm.insee.fr/series/sdmx/conceptscheme/"
res2 <- getURL(url2)
xmlToList(res2)
# encoding kept
```

Why the behaviour about encoding is different ? I tried to set `.encoding = "UTF-8"` in `getURL`, and to `enc2utf8(res)` but that makes no change.

Any help is welcome !

Thanks,

Jérémy

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.7 bitops_1.0-6   XML_3.98-1.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.1
```

Comment: Try with `res <- getURL(url, .encoding = "CE_LATIN1")`.

Comment: with `CE_LATIN1` the encoding is lost during `getURL`, before calling `xmlToList`

Comment: That's bad. It works for me.

Comment: It works still after applying `xmlToList` ? Then it is maybe due to the locale or something. Thanks for help anyway

Comment: `[1] "Institut national de la statistique et des études économiques"`. My locale is `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: `[1] "Institut national de la statistique et des Ã©tudes Ã©conomiques"` here

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read SDMX documents in R. I would suggest to use the [rsdmx](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rsdmx) package that makes easier the reading of SDMX documents. The package is available on CRAN, you can also access the latest version on [Github](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx).

rsdmx allows you to read SDMX documents by `file` or `url`, e.g.

```
require(rsdmx)
sdmx = readSDMX("http://www.bdm.insee.fr/series/sdmx/data/DEFAILLANCES-ENT-FR-ACT/M.AZ+BE.BRUT+CVS-CJO?lastNObservations=2")
as.data.frame(sdmx)
```

Another approach is to use the web-service interface to embedded data providers, and INSEE is one of them. Try:

```
sdmx <- readSDMX(providerId = "INSEE", resource = "data",
                 flowRef = "DEFAILLANCES-ENT-FR-ACT",
                 key = "M.AZ+BE.BRUT+CVS-CJO", key.mode = "SDMX",
                 start = 2010, end = 2015)
as.data.frame(sdmx)
```

AFAIK the package also contains issues to the character encoding, but i'm currently investigating a solution to make available soon in the package. Calling `getURL(file, .encoding="UTF-8")` properly retrieves data, but encoding is lost calling `xml` functions.

Note: I also see you use a parameter `lastNObservations`. For the moment the web-service interface does not support extra parameters, but it may be made available quite easily if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for redirecting to this package ! It seems very convenient, I will have a deeper look at it. Keep me updated if you find a solution for the encoding problem.

Comment: @jlesuffleur sorry to come back only now. From rsdmx version 0.5-2, i've put in place some mechanism to make sure proper encoding is set. Note that in rsdmx, we wrap the SDMX document with dedicated classes, at this level i didn't (yet) find a way to properly encode textual content, hence the encoding fix is applied when you call a ``as.data.frame`` function on a R ``SDMX*`` object. Do not hesitate to follow rsdmx on Github, and in case report bugs or suggest improvements.